# Perl removing words from file1 with file2

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I am using a perl script to remove all stopwords in a text. The stop words are stored one by line. I am using Mac OSX command line and perl is installed correctly.

This script is not working properly and has a boundary problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
# usage: script.pl words text >newfile
use English;

# poor man's argument handler
open(WORDS, shift @ARGV) || die "failed to open words file: $!";
open(REPLACE, shift @ARGV) || die "failed to open replacement file: $!";

my @words;
# get all words into an array
while ($_=<WORDS>) { 
  chop; # strip eol
  push @words, split; # break up words on line
}

# (optional)
# sort by length (makes sure smaller words don't trump bigger ones); ie, "then" vs "the"
@words=sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @words;

# slurp text file into one variable.
undef $RS;
$text = <REPLACE>;

# now for each word, do a global search-and-replace; make sure only words are replaced; remove possible following space.
foreach $word (@words) { 
     $text =~ s/\b\Q$word\E\s?//sg;
}

# output "fixed" text
print $text;
```

## sample.txt

```
$ cat sample.txt
how about i decide to look at it afterwards what
across do you think is it a good idea to go out and about i 
think id rather go up and above
```

## stopwords.txt

```
I
a
about
an
are
as
at
be
by
com
for
from
how
in
is
it
..
```

## Output:

```
$ ./remove.pl stopwords.txt sample.txt 
i decide look fterwards cross do you think good idea go out d i 
think id rather go up d bove
```

As you can see, it replaces afterwards using a as fterwards. Think its a regex problem. Please can somebody help me to patch this quickly? Thanks for all the help :J

Comment: Shouldn't there be another `\b` in `s/\b\Q$word\E\s?//sg;` so that: `s/\b\Q$word\E\b//sg;`

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thats it, post that as answer. :J

Comment: Also: Turn on `strict` and `warnings`. Lexical 3 arg file opens are a good idea, especially when you're getting the filename off the arg list. You also don't need to explicitly assign `$_` in your while loop. If you're doing that, either use a different (meaningful) name or just don't - `while ( <$file>) ` does exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word-boundary on both sides of your `$word`. Currently, you are only checking for it at the beginning.

You won't need the `\s?` condition with the `\b` in place:

```
$text =~ s/\b\Q$word\E\b//sg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not strict enough.

```
$text =~ s/\b\Q$word\E\s?//sg;
```

When `$word` is `a`, the command is effectively `s/\ba\s?//sg`. This means, remove all occurrences of a new word starting with `a` followed by zero or more whitespace. In `afterwards`, this will successfully match the first `a`.

You can make the match more stricter by ending word with another `\b`. Like

```
$text =~ s/\b\Q$word\E\b\s?//sg;
```